# How to show only oldest and newest node in Drupal views?

Tags: drupal, view

I want to create a view that only shows the oldest and newest node of a certain content type what is the easiest way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with [hook_views_query_alter](http://views.doc.logrus.com/). However, for a code-less approach I would recommend creating two views. One view to grab the oldest and another view to grab the newest node for your content type. You can then use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to place these views right next to each other giving the illusion they are one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest method to do this with Views UI.

1) Create a **views display** (page, block etc) with filters of Content type and Published, limit it to display only One node and Sort by date published ascending. This will show the oldest node.

2) In the same views add an **Attachment** display. Use the same filters and limitations and change only (by overriding this display) the sorting to descending. This way you will get the latest node.